# MyMoneyTracker dump file content at Android os

Tags: android, sqlite, dump, database-dump

Nice to see you!

[MyMoneyTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ic.myMoneyTracker&hl) backup database (dump) file has some specific encoding, i suppose. It's sqlite3 dump file. In difference with regular text dump file it has a lot of "^@" and other "^" symbols like "^G" or "^H".

Is it possible to create(generate) similar file by standalone sqlite3 on my machine to use it as backup within MyMoneyTracker? In other words, to substitute one with my own data.

First string from dump file:

SQLite format 3^@^P^@^A^A^@@  ^@^@^@<8a>^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^N^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^K^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@    ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<8a>^@-т#^M   Ќ^@^N^E^Y^@^OЇ^Nк^N<88>^Lф^L^Q^K(

One another string from dump file:

```
CREATE TABLE Budgets(_id integer primary key autoincrement,BudgetName text not null,OpenDate integer not null,CloseDate integer not null    , CurrencyID int null)<81>^K^N^G^W^[^[^A<81>mtableHistoryHistory^PCREATE TABLE History (_id integer primary key autoincrement,ActionDate     integer not null, SQLQuery text not null)<81>Z^M^G^W^U^U^A<83>^WtableDebtDebt^OCREATE TABLE Debt (_id integer primary key autoincrement    ,Whom text not null,Type integer not null, AccountID integer not null, InitialBallance real not null,Date integer not null,Comments not     null)<81>^W^L^G^W;;^A<81>EtableAccountCurrecyAssigmentAccountCurrecyAssigment^NCREATE TABLE AccountCurrecyAssigment (AccountID integer n    ot null,CurrecyID integer not null)<81>%^K^G^W%%^A<82>^MtableExcangeRatesExcangeRates^MCREATE TABLE ExcangeRates (SourceCurrecyID intege    r not null,DestinationCurrencyID integer not null, ExchanageRate real not null)<81>^V
```

Comment: What is right at the beginning of the dump file?

Comment: @CL, I edited the question as you ask me

Answer (score 0):

That file is a database file, probably just a copy of the actual database.

You can open with any tool that supports SQLite3 databases, such as the [sqlite3 command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html), or [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

Comment: Ok, how can I substitute or alter it with new data.